# Exception in folder tree stucture in jstree

Tags: jquery, treeview, jstree

I'm trying to create a tree structure in jstree. Infact i have done it successfully during testing(as a sample app).

But when I integrated it with the web project I'm working on it gives an exception.It doesn't even display the folders as a structure 
I can't figure our why
This is the exception i'm getting

```
uncaught exception: TypeError: contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] is undefined
```

this is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="_lib/sarissa.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_lib/sarissa_ieemu_xpath.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_lib/jquery.xslt.js"></script

<div id="demo1" style="width:200px;">
    <ul>
        <li id="phtml_1">
            <a href="#">Root node 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li id="phtml_2">
                    <a href="#">Child node 1.1</a>
                </li>
                <li id="phtml_3">
                    <a href="#">Child node 2.2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="phtml_4">
            <a href="#">Root node 2</a>
                <ul>
                <li id="phtml_2">
                    <a href="#">Child node 2.1</a>
                </li>
                <li id="phtml_3">
                    <a href="#">Child node 2.2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="phtml_4">
            <a href="#">Root node 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="value"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    $("#demo1").jstree({        
    }).bind("loaded.jstree", function (event, data) {               
    }); 

});
</script>
```

I would be glad if someone could help me out.
thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have HEAD element in your HTML page?

Comment: Hi Ankur, sorry about the late reply.I could just attend this problem.
In fact the project I'm working on has only one main page with all the html elements.All the other pages are loaded inside a <div> in the main page.In the main page there is the head element.
Now the exception prompts very often out of the blue and disappears just like that.The system gives unusual output.I was wondering whether this exception has to do something with it.So I would appreciate any help regarding this.